# Downloading Image from Firebase Storage in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

So I try to download an image from the Firebase Storage. I tried to do it the way Firebase recommends to on their website. In the following I show you my code, but there is a problem. When I am downloading the image I have a `OnSuccessListener`. I applied a Log.d to it so I know that it gets triggered. But I can't find the image I tried to download on my smartphone.

This is my Code:

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(photoURL);

final File imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                         .getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFolder/");

storageReference.getFile(imageFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
     holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     holder.downloadBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
     holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     holder.downloadBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onProgress(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
     int progress = (int) ((100 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
     holder.progressBar.setProgress(progress);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're not saving I.T as an image file.

Try this

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
     holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     holder.downloadBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    String filename = "yourfilename.png";
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); //You might wanna add something to sd that leads to your preferred path e.g /DCIM or /camera.
    File dest = new File(sd, filename);

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
    try {
         FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
         bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
         out.flush();
         out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Better replace

```
final File imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                     .getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFolder/");
```

with this:

```
final File imageFile= File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");
```

Comment: can you include your code into mine. I don't really know where I have to put this code snippet. Thank you

Comment: Roger that Karl. There you go :)